# Using mutate+case_when to create a new column by comparing the value of a column in a df to a set vectors

Tags: dplyr

I am trying to use dplyr::mutate to create a new column in a df based on a couple of conditions, but I am getting back an error telling me that the objects I am comparing (vectors vs df$column) have unequal lengths. Here's the error message:

**Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `Analye_Class = case_when(...)`.
Caused by error in `` names(message) <- `*vtmp*` ``:
! 'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.**

I figured out how to do so using the %in% operator and would like to find out how to achieve the same result using dplyr:mutate.

I started by defining two vectors called, "Class1" and "Class2" to asign each observation to class based on wheter the value of the "Analyte" column in found on either of the vectors.

Below is my code:

```
library(dplyr)

Class1 <- c("a","b")
Class2 <- c("c","d")
df <- data.frame (Site = c("A","A","B","B","C","C"),
            Analyte = c("a","b","a","b","c","d"),
            Class = rep(c("NA"),6))

#If value of "Analyte" column is found in vectors "Class1" or "Class2" then 
#set value of "Class" column to name of corresponding vector, using %in% operator

df1 <- within(df,{
  Class=NA
  Class[Analyte %in% Class1]="Class1"
  Class[Analyte %in% Class2]="Class2"
})
df1

#If value of "Analyte" column is found in vectors "Class1" or "Class2" then 
#set value of "Class" column to name of corresponding vector, using dplyr::mutate produces 
#unequal length error message

df2 <- df%>%dplyr::mutate(Analye_Class = case_when(
  Analyte %in% Class1 ~ "Class1",
  Analyte %in% Class2 ~ "Class2",
  TRUE~NA
))
df2
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `NA_character_` instead of `NA`

```r
library(dplyr)

Class1 <- c("a","b")
Class2 <- c("c","d")
df <- data.frame (Site = c("A","A","B","B","C","C"),
                  Analyte = c("a","b","a","b","c","d"),
                  Class = rep(c("NA"),6))


df2 <- df %>% dplyr::mutate(Analye_Class = case_when(
    Analyte %in% Class1 ~ "Class1",
    Analyte %in% Class2 ~ "Class2",
    TRUE ~ NA_character_
))

df2

#>   Site Analyte Class Analye_Class
#> 1    A       a    NA       Class1
#> 2    A       b    NA       Class1
#> 3    B       a    NA       Class1
#> 4    B       b    NA       Class1
#> 5    C       c    NA       Class2
#> 6    C       d    NA       Class2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much! I had no idea the error message had to do with using NA instead of NA_character. The error message is so cryptic, it would be better if it said that the default value class (NA= Logical) does not match the case_when class (Character). Learned something new today, thank you.